# Load PDF in fancybox or any similar jQuery popup

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf, popup

Is it possible to load a PDF file in a popup? I know that some browser are not able to read PDF files without adobe reader, but chrome have one inside the browser itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an iframe which linked to the file itself, but as you said, many browsers will simply download it instead of displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would reccomend using [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/), I have used it several times and have had no compatibility issues with it. I don't believe you even have to register to upload your documents and you simply embed the object code they give you into your html.

```
<object id="doc_990161104538135" style="outline: none;" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="660" height="900" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="data" value="http://d1.scribdassets.com/ScribdViewer.swf"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="bgcolor" value="#333333"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="FlashVars" value="document_id=50304719&amp;access_key=key-ob2lgtlteak2lawdxw3&amp;page=1&amp;viewMode=list"><param name="src" value="http://d1.scribdassets.com/ScribdViewer.swf"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><embed id="doc_990161104538135" style="outline: none;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="660" height="900" src="http://d1.scribdassets.com/ScribdViewer.swf" flashvars="document_id=50304719&amp;access_key=key-ob2lgtlteak2lawdxw3&amp;page=1&amp;viewMode=list" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" bgcolor="#333333" wmode="opaque" data="http://d1.scribdassets.com/ScribdViewer.swf"></object>
```

Comment: Do you know if the file needs to be hosted on their server or can you point to a pdf locally?